# cannot make a select option using option framework in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new user in WordPress. I have a problem in option framework. I cannot make options for my use. I want a box which contains font name where the user can select. that is why I use this code in `functions.options.php`:

```
$of_options[] = array(  "name"  => "Select Google Font",
                    "desc"  => "Normal Select Box.",
                     "id"   => "google_font_select",
                     "type" => "select",
                     "options" => array("PT Sans","Open Sans","Droid Sans")
                  );
```

but it doesn't shows me a select box. it shows like this image in admin panel.

[image]

please help me in this issue.

Comment: Your options need to be a key => value pair array like:
`"options" => array(
    'no' => 'no',
    'yes' => 'yes'
)`

Comment: hi thanks for reply.it does not work. I use your code but the problem is still same.

Comment: Can you add some more code of your options

Comment: i didnt understand. after adding my codes all other tabs are disable. can click on that but the tab is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I have just used the select with multiple options in options framework. Here is what i have done in one of my project.

First, i have made an array of text for options value for selection.

And, here is the actual code. That i successfully run in my website.

```
$options[] = array(
        'name' => __('Services', 'ascent'),
        'type' => 'heading');

$text_array=array('java','c#','php');

    $options[] = array(
        'name' => __('Service Title', 'ascent'),
        'desc' => __('Change title', 'ascent'),
        'id' => 's_title1',
        'type' => 'select',
        'options'=>$text_array);

return $options;
```

Hope, this will helps you to used in your project.